# How incomplete ClojureScript now? (range) (iterate) etc

Tags: node.js, clojure, clojurescript

I'm trying to use ClojureScript instead Clojure lately.

When I compile and run on node.js

```
(.log js/console (range 10))
```

I've got

```
$ node app      
{ meta: null,
  start: 0,
  end: 10,
  step: 1,
  __hash: null,
  'cljs$lang$protocol_mask$partition1$': 0,
  'cljs$lang$protocol_mask$partition0$': 32375006 }
```

I'm a bit surprised to see this simple code does not work.

Is this due to my specific environment? I hope so, and if it's a problem of my side, please advise.

Here is the compiled js:

```
cljs.nodejs = {};
cljs.nodejs.require = require;
cljs.nodejs.process = process;
cljs.core.string_print = cljs.nodejs.require.call(null, "util").print;
var rxcljs = {core:{}};
console.log(cljs.core.range.call(null, 10));
```

Comment: Why do you think it does not work? It looks like that `node app` command successfully printed internals of range object created with `(range 10)`. What did you expect to see?

Comment: Well, leinREPL at least evaluates user=> (range 10)
(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either `console.log` the string representation of `(range 10)`:

```
(.log js/console (pr-str (range 10)))
```

or simply use the `println` function:

```
(println (range 10))
```

In either case, `(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)` is printed as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to print the vector instead; `range` returns a lazy seq.

Try this:

```
(.log js/console (vec (range 10)))
```